# Cron to read from multiple crontab files for each system

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron, aix

I have a large landscape of servers. There are logical groupings for some servers (clusters). I'd find a way to run crontabs on specific clusters. Specifically, I'd like to have a centralized location were I can edit their crontabs at the same time. 
Currently, what I'm doing is accessing each server and editing their crontabs the manual way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider a tool like Ansible which would allow you to manage the cron entries or cron files locally, and distribute them to your servers.

Ansible is quite easy to learn and all you need is Ansible, Python and a working ssh connection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not too familiar with tools like Ansible. I'm currently reading it up. Does Ansible allow you to see all your systems' crontabs and manage them concurrently?

Comment: Not really _see_, but you could group servers with the Ansible `hosts` file, and manage crontab entries (or better still, files in `/etc/cron.d`) based on group membership with the Ansible `cron` module.